# How to arrange custom posts in the backend/admin by custom taxonomy

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php

I’ve got a plug-in that uses a custom post type which allows custom taxonomies. The post type is employees and the the custom taxonomy is company. What I want to do is group all the employees(custom post) to the companies they are apart of, they can only be assign to one company. Is this possible? I can do easily front end through a template. I can’t work out how to create a sorting ability in the admin par the date.

Comment: I don't believe that `WP_Query` supports this, the solution to this won't be as easy as it looks, and will probably involve complex raw SQL, as well as a big performance hit. See here for the available options for sorting/order https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: @TomJNowell okay, bit of a shame but I’ll work around it. Not worth the development time. Thank you for confirmation though